# Does Redis support master-master replication?

Tags: redis, database-replication, multi-master-replication

From my understanding from the below questions which were asked quite some time back, Redis doesn't have a built-in support for master-master replication.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519971/redis-mimic-master-master-or-something-else)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232522/using-redis-replication-on-different-machines-multi-master)

[Question 3](https://serverfault.com/questions/538611/setting-up-multiple-redis-masters)

The official website as of now looks like there is nothing much to it about master-master replication. Is this still the case, i.e., does Redis still have no options for multi-master replication. And even third-party tools don't seem to be helping Redis achieve the same. I came accross Zabcluster and Zookeeper but I'm not sure if this would meet my requirement of a simple master-master setup without much additional complex changes.

[ZabCluster](https://github.com/Pansion/zabcluster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your research is accurate - at the moment, Redis does not provide multi-master.

Comment: Sorry, edified to "doesn't"

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber !! What about the third-party ones? Zabcluster for example?

Comment: Never heard of it until today... And it looks somewhat unmaintained